# Obtain Key Check Value (KCV or KVV) of 3DES Key

Tags: c#, cryptography, tripledes

I know How to calculate the KCV of the *[single-length DES](http://eftcalculator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=key%20check%20value)* key i-e by encrypting 16 hexadecimal zeroes using the key.

I followed the Example in the link above and matched my answer that was correct (Implemented that in C#):

```
Zeros = StringToByte("0000000000000000");
Key   = StringToByte("0123456789ABCDEF");

KCV = cryptographer.EncryptDES(Zeros ,Key); // KCV Single DES

D5D44FF720683D0D = ByteToString(KCV); // Answer matched from the Link above and its correct
```

**Question:**
 What I want to know is How to obtain KCV of **Triple DES** Key? Like this:

```
 firstKey = secondKey = 16 Digit key.
            Result = cryptographer.EncryptDES(Zeros , firstKey);
            Result = cryptographer.DecryptDES(Result, secondKey);
            Result = cryptographer.EncryptDES(Result, thirdKey);

Where ,
       thirdKey = firstKey.
```

Even googling didn't work for me. Help is appreciated!

Comment: This should work. I looked into the source code you've linked to and it does use K1==K3 for a 16 byte key. There is probably some encoding problem. Can you provide a full, runnable example?